# How to check if $x_{100}$ is prime or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have $$x_{n}=5x_{n-1}-4x_{n-2}+6$$ and I have found that the $n$-th term is$$x_{n}=-{1\over3}+{7\over12}\cdot4^n-2n$$ I must demonstrate if $x_{100}$ is a prime number or not. How should I begin? I must find if $x_{100}$ is divisible by $3$ or not.

Comment: what are values of  $x_0, x_1$?

Comment: $x_1$=0 and $x_2$=5

Answer (score 6):

Your initial conditions are
$$x_1=0\ ,\quad x_2=5\ .$$
(I got these from your formula for $x_n$.)  Modulo $3$ the recurrence is
$$x_n\equiv 2x_{n-1}+2x_{n-2}\ ,$$
which gives the values
$$x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3,\,\ldots\equiv 0,\,2,\,1,\,0,\,2,\,\ldots\ .$$
Note that the sequence now repeats.  So the terms which are divisible by $3$ (that is, $0$ mod $3$) are
$$x_1,\,x_4,\,x_7,\,x_{10},\,\ldots$$
. . . and $x_{100}$.

Comment: So, if $x_{100}$ is divisible by 3 I can say $x_{100}$ is a prime number?

Comment: If it's divisible by $3$ then it's **not** a prime number, unless it's equal to $3$.  And it's clear from your formula that $x_{100}$ is way bigger than $3$.

Comment: this recurrence $$x_{n}=2x_{n-1}+2x_{n-2}$$ is apply for all exercises for this type? If I have another sequence, I will apply the recurrence gave it by you?

Comment: No, you will need to learn about [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: can you write step-by-step the recurrence for $x_n$? it is pretty hard to understand what you did there

Comment: $5\equiv2$ and $-4\equiv2$ modulo $3$.  Did you look up modular arithmetic? - if not, this is going to be pretty hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

$$x_n=-{1\over3}+{7\over3}4^{n-1}-2n$$

> $x_n$ is an integer for all $n\ge1$.

Proof:
$$7\cdot4^{n-1}\equiv1\cdot1^{n-1}=1\mod 3$$
So fractional part of $x_n=-{1\over3}+{1\over3}=0$.

> $x_{100}$ is  divisible by $3$.

Proof:
$$7\cdot4^{100-1}\equiv7\cdot64^{33}\equiv7\cdot1^{33}=7\mod 9\\
200\equiv2\mod 3$$
So fractional part of ${x_{100}\over3}=-{1\over9}+{7\over9}-{2\over3}=0$.

$$$$